# Why Client Certificate is required in Azure’s Point to Site VPN connection?

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

As a reference guide for creating Root Certificate for Point to Site VPN connection, I have gone through some web links.

In all links, I found, Root Certificate and Client Certificate are created but on Azure Portal, only Root Certificate information has been added at Virtual Gateway Network’s P2S Connection.

Then, why Client Certificate has been created as it was not added on the Azure portal?

Regards

TekQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Azure certificate authentication type in the point-to-site configuration in the virtual network gateway. You upload the root certificate (including the **public key** information) to the Azure portal, which is considered to be **"trust"** by Azure for connection over P2S to the virtual network. A client certificate that is generated from the root certificate. The client certificate (including the **private key** information) installed on each client computer that will connect to the VNet. **This certificate is used for client authentication**. That means only the client who installed a client certificate are allowed to connect to this P2S VPN connection.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal#generatecert

Comment: As you said, "That means only the client who installed a client certificate are allowed to connect to this P2S VPN connection." We generate root certificate and client certificate both form a client computer for P2S VPN connection. Then, we add the detail of root certificate in VPN Gateway. Does it mean, we need to install the client certificate in the same computer from where it has been generated?

Comment: Yes, if you are generating a self-signed cert, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal#generatecert).